# How to update a table with data from another table in Alasql

Tags: sql, alasql

I'm using alasql and I am trying to update a table with data from another table, but without success.

Let's say I have a tableA as the one underneath

| id | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 31 |

And a tableB like this

| id | newAge |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 26 |
| 2 | 32 |

I tried the code below, without success, and I'm stuck.

```
UPDATE
    tableA
INNER JOIN 
    tableB 
ON 
    tableA.id = tableB.Id 
SET
    tableA.age = tableB.newAge
```

Hope you can help. Thanks!